# "Skipping 3 packages not available: memoise, digest, lubidate" - yet these packages are downloaded

Tags: r, package

Trying to install the smwrBase package with remotes::install_github and get this error:

```
Skipping 3 packages not available: memoise, digest, lubidate
```

and

```
Error: (converted from warning) package "lubridate" was built under R version 4.0.2
```

However, I have R 4.0.0, tried updating to 4.2 w/ no change, I have the listed packages and updating them doesn't make this error go away.

Comment: See https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1929

Comment: Try installing those from CRAN yourself: `install.packages(c("memoise", "digest", "lubridate"))`

Comment: @MrFlick, I did that with no change. I also get a popup at the start of RStudio "The procedure entry point EXTPTR_PTR could not be located in the dynamic link library ..../R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/libs/i386/Rcpp.dll" I have 64bt system, but many packages have i386 folders

Comment: Also, a WARNING to install RTools, but I've downloaded it, too.

Comment: Hmm. Something seems to have gotten very messed up. I’m very surprised you get the same error when using install.packages.  So when you run sessionInfo() is says you are running 64 bit R? Have you manually set which version of R that RStudio uses?

Comment: @MrFlick Ah, sessionInfo() is helpful.. I've been operating with the 32bit version of R. When changing to 64bit I get the error "internet routines could not be loaded" and can't reset my wd. Going to try to delete all R system files & reinstall my packages to see if that fixes things.

Comment: For Archive: Deleted old 4.0.0 R files. With 4.0.2 version, the package was able to install and work fine while running R 32bit on my 64bit WIndows.

Comment: I got similar error messages even after installing all those, missing, package (only available from Bioconductor) before this step.  I am guessing, it might be due to the default R repository (CRAN) does not have these packages, because of my dependent packages are only available from BioConductor, not in the BASE-R.  So we could ignore this warning.